# Invalid amount in MetaMask app on iPhone

Tags: metamask, transfer, moralis

I am using Moralis for simple token transfer from one wallet to another. My code:

[image]

And this works great on desktop (Chrome MetaMask plugin):

[image]

But when I wanna use this on my phone - iPhone (MetaMask app), I always get error "Invalid amount", and I don't understand why, since I am executing same code.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with the mobile MetaMask wallet and iOS. I faced absolutely the same error and am unable to find a solution. I've tried calling the contract directly with ethers.js and using the WC signer, still the same effect.

It works with MetaMask on Android though...